# Spatial complexity estimative of a recursion function

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm learning algorithms and data structures and I'm now on the part of time and space complexity.

I have to solve a problem and them tell (based on my code) the time and spatial complexity.

This is the code:

```
public class B {

    public static int minSum = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int objects, sumA = 0, sumB = 0;

        Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        objects = readInput.nextInt();

        int[] trunk = new int[objects];

        if (objects == 0) {
            System.out.print(0 + "\n");
        } else if (objects == 1) {
            trunk[0] = readInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print(trunk[0] + "\n");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < objects; i++) {
                trunk[i] = readInput.nextInt();
            }

            bruteforce(trunk, sumA, sumB, 0);

            System.out.println(minSum);
        }
    }

    public static void bruteforce(int[] trunk, int sumA, int sumB, int index) {
        int partialDiff;

        if (minSum == 0) {
            System.out.println(minSum);
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (index == trunk.length) {
            partialDiff = Math.abs(sumA - sumB);
            if (partialDiff < minSum || minSum == -1) {
                minSum = partialDiff;
            }
        } else {
            bruteforce(trunk, sumA + trunk[index], sumB, index + 1);
            bruteforce(trunk, sumA, sumB + trunk[index], index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the user first inputs a number of objects and then inputs, for each object, its value. The algorithm  will distribute the objects by two bags and must calculate the min difference that can be calculated when distributing the objects by the two bags.

I believe that it takes exponential time but I'm struggling with an estimative for the spatial complexity. Can you point me In some direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space complexity is linear - `O(n)`.

You calculate this by multiplying the amount of memory used in each function call by the max recursion depth.

There is a constant amount of memory being used in each function call - just `partialDiff` and stack information.

To determine the max recursion depth, you can basically just look at `index` (since this is the variable that decides when it stops recursing deeper).

- You call the function with `index` = 0.
- At each recursive call, `index` increases by one.
- As soon as `index` reaches the size of the array, it stops.

Note that function calls are depth-first, meaning it will completely evaluate the first call to `bruteforce` before the second call, thus only one will take up memory at a time.

So, for an array of length 2, it goes something like this: (`Call 1` is the first function call, `Call 2` the second)

```
Call with index 0
  Call 1 with index 1
    Call 1 with index 2
    Call 2 with index 2
  Call 2 with index 1
    Call 1 with index 2
    Call 2 with index 2
```

So the max depth (and thus space complexity) is 3, one more than the number of items in the array.

So it's `memory used in each function call * max depth = constant * linear = linear`.

Comment: Sweet. Many thanks. Just for clarification. It's O(2^n) time complexity isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, each function call creates 2 branches, so you end up with 2^n branches, thus O(2^n).